# I have 3 divs each with it's own topic, and now I would like for each div to open its modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far I manage to open one modal by clicking on any of the divs. How can I have one modal for one div element, that is I would like when I click on services to open services modal, and when I click on about to open about modal...and so on..I also have to close every modal when one is opend...I dont know how to connect each div with it's own modal. This is the code I have...

```
<div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>Services</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
            <div class="over">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>About me</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i>
            <div class="over">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 sector">
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            <div class="over">
              <span class="tooltiptext">Show more...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-container" id="myMod">
     <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times</span>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <p>Some text goes in here...</p>
     </div>
</div>
  <div class="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Got Ideas?</h1>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sed sem rhoncus urna iaculis faucibus. Pellentesque ultrices nibh ac imperdiet tincidunt. Donec hendrerit velit eros</p>
        <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the button that opens the modal
     var myOver = document.getElementsByClassName('over');
     // Get modal to pass it to function
     var modal = document.getElementById('myMod');
     // get closing button
     var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
     // Function to open the modal
     for(var i = 0; i<myOver.length; i++){
        myOver[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
         modal.style.display = 'block';
        });
     }


    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display='none';
    }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a similar naming scheme and find the right text simply by by appending a suffix to the object that was clicked on's id, for instance have each span element have an id corresponding to the modal they go with. For instance `contact` then have the click event listener be

```
function(e) { //e is the event object event
   document.getElementById(e.target.id + "-modal").style.display = 'block'
}
```

now id the contact modal as 'contact-modal' and it should find it easily

As for closing each element, just iterate through all elements with the class `modal-contain` and set their `display` to `none` before opening the 
new one